# How to fix hang 1 table on 40 tables when I use query on that table

Tags: c#-4.0

I have 1 database on sql about 30 tables. everyday I have about 10 user access database via software client. but I must restart server 1 or 2 times when 1 table on databse not running when I check query with that table query not running but I restart server query with that table is running. Can u help me about that reason? Thank you verymuch!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio you can check Activity Monitor for the queries running when its hanging, it will help to troubleshoot the issue.